# The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#1c11f OVERFLOWING

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors, flutter-layout

I was trying to add a bunch of widget inside the Column and the root widget is Material. The simple code is throwing error and I cannot understand why it is causing error.
My code is:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('234')
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The Error is:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99263 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Column 
lib\main.dart:14
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#1c11f OVERFLOWING
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 1 of 513 libraries in 707ms.
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Put this

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Form(
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that your Column has an infinite height.

Some things you could do:

- put everything in a `Scaffold` `body`
- add `height` attribute to your `Container`
- put `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to you `Column`